# I am trying to create a hyperlink with an image

Tags: html, image, hyperlink

I can't seem to get it to work though. I would really appreciate some help. Thank you! Below is the code I am writing:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<h1>forever alone :/</h1>
<div>
<p>
<>
</p>
</div>
</body>
```

Comment: you want to give hyperlink to the image right?

Comment: Your missing the image!

Answer (score 2):

```
<a href="whatever.com or whatever.html"><img src="your_image_name.jpg"></a>
```

Answer (score 1):

All you have to do is put an `<img>` tag inside an `<a>` tag to get an image that's also a hyperlink.

Example:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <body>
    <h1>forever alone :/</h1>
    <a href="https://www.google.com">
      <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/350x150">
    </a>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you. I had that, but for some reason when I posted this stack overflow told me that I had to take it out.

This is the way I typed it out:

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
  <h1>forever alone :/</h1>
  <div>
    <p>
      <img src="https://me.me/i/forever-alone-foreveralone-meme-rageface-trollface-aa4e37a49b5048038c9974eeab5eca14" alt="alone">
    </p>
  </div>
</body>
</html>

Comment: I realized that I didn't have an <a> tag. I guess that's what was making it not work.

Comment: Yup, that would explain it actually. The `<a>` (or anchor) tag is what defines a hyperlink. And inside you can just put some text or other HTML elements (like an `img` in this case).

Answer (score 0):

Try to do like this :

JS fiddle : [code](https://jsfiddle.net/abhishekpakhare/vpwa01ch/1/)

`<a href = "www.google.com"><img src="http://lorempixel.com/400/200"></a>`

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<h1>forever alone :/</h1>
<div>
<p>
<a href="www.google.com">
  <img src="http://lorempixel.com/400/200" alt="">
</a>
</p>
</div>
</body>
```

Comment: Thank you. I will try that.

Comment: I copied your comment and saved it as a file in atom, and it worked! I pasted a link of my own from a google search image however, and it didn't work.

Comment: What issue are you facing now? I mean the link is not open or is there any error. Kindly explain a little bit more so that we can find a solution.

Comment: When I open the code with my browswer it has the header and a little dinky box where the image is supposed to be.

Comment: Kindly provide a screenshot or something. Because it is working perfectly at my end.